# Angular material table lot loading firebase content from firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

I'm trying to fetch data from a collection in Firebase's firestore in my angular application and no data is appearing, while there is data in the database. I've tried moving the fetch of the data from my data service to the component and nothing has worked there.

Component HTML File

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="communityTitle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Community Title/Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.communityTitle}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfBlacklist">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date of Blacklist </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dateOfBlacklist}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="reason">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Reason for Blacklist </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.reason}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="effectiveDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Effective Until (Date) </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.effectiveDate}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="notes">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Notes </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.notes}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Component Typescript File

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BlacklistedCommunityData } from 'src/app/interface';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/data.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rules-blacklisted-communities',
  templateUrl: './rules-blacklisted-communities.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rules-blacklisted-communities.component.scss']
})
export class RulesBlacklistedCommunitiesComponent implements OnInit {

  itemCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<BlacklistedCommunityData>
  items: Observable<BlacklistedCommunityData[]>

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemCollection = this.afs.collection('fzrpBlacklistedCommunities');
    this.items = this.itemCollection.valueChanges();
    console.log(this.items)
  }

  displayedColumns = [
    'communityTitle', 
    'dateOfBlacklist', 
    'reason', 
    'effectiveDate', 
    'notes'
  ];
  dataSource = this.items;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `dataSource = this.items;` to `dataSource.data = this.items;`

Comment: That didn't work for me as when I did change the datasource to datasource.data it threw an error saying that it expected a `;` rather than a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing `MatTableDataSource` property. Here's what you need to do. Firstly add the `MatTableDataSource` property

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IUsersList>;
```

Next, you need to call this `MatTableDataSource` property with **new keyword** to create a new instance of it and pass the data array in it.

```
let recordObj:any[] = [ //=======> records array
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John Doe',
        role: "hero1",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'John Doe',
        role: "hero2",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Troy',
        role: "hero3",
    },
]
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(recordObj); //=======> Pass records array
```

This should get it working. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Do you know how I'd change the record object to work with Firebase rather than static data?

Comment: make an http call and fetch all records requried and then simply pass them in the matdatasource property.

Comment: your service dataService should have some methods to fectch all data. Use those here

Comment: Whenever I try adding a this.____ call in the parenthasees for the MatTableDataSource it says that "Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BlacklistedCommunityData[]". This is the call `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<BlacklistedCommunityData>(this.dataService.getBlacklistedCommunities());`

I also tried this: `items = this.dataService.getBlacklistedCommunities()` and this would be what the data source is set to: `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<BlacklistedCommunityData>(this.items);`

The conditions are the same even if the data type is any or has [].